# Jquery selecting next eq(i+1) for animation on pressing button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to render animation for next image in a div, that when I press arrow button every time it render animation of next image in that div. I have tried this code please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 39) {
            $("#mydiv:eq(i)").animate({
                left: "-=50"
            });
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `template string literals` to pass the value of `i` to the `:eq` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 39) {
            $(`.thing span:eq(${i})`).animate({
                  opacity: "0.5",
                  left: "+=50"
            }, 100);
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

```css
.thing {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;

  display: block;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much it is working perfect. But is it possible to not use div:thing 2 times for 2 element because I am having a lot of elements and I want to include all the elements in single div not using separate div for every seperate element.

Comment: i dont know what this means: `But is it possible to not use div:thing 2 times for 2 element because I am having a lot of elements and I want to include all the elements in single div not using separate div for every seperate element.`

Comment: you need to explain - as if you are explaining to a small child - otherwise im just guessing at what you are trying ask... do you wish to select a div - whereby that div has many child elements... and animate those child elements?... if so - i can update the answer - and you should update the question to reflect that. Also - please upvote this answer as it helps a lot

Comment: I mean instead of using,
  <div class="thing">
    <span>0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>

Can I use it like this, 
  <div class="thing">
    <span>0</span>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>

Comment: I have also upvoted this article sir but it is saying some error in that, sorry for that (error- "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.")

Comment: one moment - i can try to upvote you more to get the thing accepted - but fixing another SO question right now - give me 15 mins

Comment: I have tried to include both spans under 1 class like this, <div class="thing"> <span>0</span> <span>1</span> </div> and then tried the jquery like "$(`.thing::nth-child(${i})`).animate({" but it is still not working

Comment: @DheerajKumar - try that now

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, you are great :)